# Spread operator to assign data inside array in an object

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I need to update the data inside the below state using spread operator.
It has to be done such a way that `data[0]` should be updated with `"vehOn":"Finance"`

```
let state = {
  "data": [{
    "year": "2017",
    "make": "ALFA ROMEO",
    "model": "ILX 4D 2.0 PREMIUM PACKAGE"
  }],
  "error": ""
};
```

Modfied state should be like:

```
let modifiedstate = {
  "data": [{
    "year": "2017",
    "make": "ALFA ROMEO",
    "model": "ILX 4D 2.0 PREMIUM PACKAGE",
    "vehOn": "Finance"
  }],
  "error": ""
};
```

Comment: _"I need to ... using spread operator"_ - Why? Please format your question/code properly? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: ...maybe...modifiedstate.data[0]["vehOn"]="Finance"???

Comment: @gaetanoM I am trying to get it done using the spread operator.

Comment: @Andreas I have tried below implementation but didn't work as expected.  :(
let oldData = state.data[0];
let newData = {'vehOn':'finance'};
let mergedData = {... oldData, ...newData};
let mergedState1 = {...state.data, ...mergedData}; //Didn't work
let mergedState2 = {...state, data:[...state.data,mergedData]}; //Didn't work

Comment: But why do you need to use the spread operator? if your intention is to clone `state` you should know that the spread operator does not make shallow copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the only way I can see to achieve your result is:

```js
let state = {
    "data": [{
        "year": "2017",
        "make": "ALFA ROMEO",
        "model": "ILX 4D 2.0 PREMIUM PACKAGE"
    }],
    "error": ""
};

let modifiedstate  = { "data": [{ ...state.data[0], ...{vehOn: "Finance"} }],
    "error": ""};

console.log(modifiedstate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const state = {
  "data": [{
    "year": "2017",
    "make": "ALFA ROMEO",
    "model": "ILX 4D 2.0 PREMIUM PACKAGE"
  }],
  "error": ""
};

console.log("---- state ----");
console.log(state);

const modifiedstate = { ...state,
  data: state.data.map((entry, i) => i === 0 ? ({ ...entry,
    vehOn: "Finance"
  }) : entry)
};

console.log("---- modifiedstate ----");
console.log(modifiedstate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to create an object that is identical to state and you don't know what properties `state` can have you should look for a way to [deep clone it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Otherwise if you are absolutely sure of the structure of `state` and want to do a simple clone you can do the following:

```
   let modifiedstate = "data": [{
     ...state.data[0],
     "vehOn": "Finance"
     }],
     "error": ""
   }
```